# Python How to Initialize Reader Object in Class Definition

Tags: python, class

I want to make a singleton class that gathers data from a csv file, and in order to do that, it needs to have a data member of type DictReader; but I am not sure how I would initialize this member in the class definition, as it can only be initialized like so:

```
with open('sourceFile.csv') as source:
    reader = csv.DictReader(source)
```

Because Python will not allow you to declare variables without initialization, I need to know how I can initialize the reader object in the class Singleton.

Comment: Do you know about the [`__init__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__)?

Comment: Oh yeah. That would probably work. If it does, I will close the question.

Comment: Wow. I didn't think this question was going to get a single up vote. Now, I'm over 100. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like:

```
class MySingleton(object):
    def __init__(self, source):
        self.my_reader = DictReader(source)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    singleton = MySingleton(sourcefile)
    for row in singleton.my_reader:
        # do stuff
```

Comment: Awesome! That was totally helpful.